# Storing Array of Objects in localStorage and dynamically display them with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form where a user will input their contact details.

They can then choose to submit the form or press add another person.

If they choose to add another person then the data in the form is passed into local storage.

From there the user can input as many peoples details as they need to with all the data being stored locally.

I then need to be able to display the stored data above the form so that they can see what they have already added.

This is what I have which is where the data is displayed

```html
<div class="guestTable" id="guestview"></div>
```

And this is what is passing it into dynamic HTML to be displayed.

```html
<script>
let guests_deserialized = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("guests"));

      let html = "<div>"; // Build the div output
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < guests_deserialized.length; i++) {
        html += `<div id='guests${i}'>`; // If you add a button to remove a guest you can use the counter similarly to determine which element you want to delete.
        html += guests_deserialized[i].firstName + "<br>";
        html += guests_deserialized[i].lastName + "<br>";
        /* html += guests_deserialized[i].email + "<br>";
        html += guests_deserialized[i].mobileNumber + "<br><br>"; */
        html += "</div>";
      }
      html += "</html>";
      localStorage.setItem("guestshtml", html);
    }); /* resets the form */

    /* document.querySelector('form').reset(); */
  </script>

  <script>
    let guests_html = localStorage.getItem("guestshtml"); // Display the guests data
    document.getElementById("guestview").innerHTML = guests_html;
  </script>
```

Currently the output is like so

fName

lName

I would like to display the data in a table like so

Guest 1 fName lName (remove)

I have searched here, google and YouTube for help but I am coming up empty. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you recreate a demo version of your problem scenario on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Im very new to this. I have just tried jsfiddle.net and it just gives me a 404 error when I try and run the code. This isnt the case with the actual document. I will add it just in case it helps though.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jpicton/rcys3ax8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive written a quick example on jsFiddle: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/0y7bLd48/)

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="addEntry(event)" >
 <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/>
 <input type="text" name= "lname" id="lname"/>
 <button>
  Add
 </button>
</form>

<div class="guestTable" id="guestview"></div>
```

JS:

```
addEntry = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  let entries = []
  let fname =  document.getElementById("fname").value
  let lname =  document.getElementById("lname").value

  if(localStorage.getItem('guests')){
    entries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('guests')) 
    entries.push({fname,lname})
    localStorage.setItem('guests',JSON.stringify(entries))
   }else{
    entries.push({fname,lname})
    localStorage.setItem('guests',JSON.stringify([{fname,lname}]))
   }

  let html =''
  for(i=0;i<entries.length;i++){
   html += '<div>'+entries[i].fname+' '+entries[i].lname+'</div>'
  }
 document.getElementById("guestview").innerHTML= html
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the output was the same

fName lName stacked on top of each other and I cant style them.

Comment: @user13684791, how do you want to style them? I will edit my code.

Comment: "Guest | First Name | Last Name | Remove"

Comment: I cant write a multi-line response so ive split it in two. I already have a counter I can use to show the number of the guest in col1, in col2 I would like the fName, in col3 I would like the lName and col4 I would like a button to remove that guest.

Comment: If you could just add the button tags in with a class I will workout the button script part out. I haven't been able to even start looking at that as I cant get past this step. I also what to say thank you for your help. Ive been pulling my hair out.

Comment: you want to remove from localStorage?

Comment: pls see the updated code here : https://jsfiddle.net/0y7bLd48/

Comment: That is perfect thank you very much. It makes sense now when I see it. 

Yeah the remove button just needs to remove that persons details from storage. So that when they do submit, only the details they confirm are passed through to a cloud function.

Comment: When refresh the data does not display, also what is the submit button for? Thanks